# How to include options within selectInput() from a data frame in local without pre-reloading it in R memory

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am unable to run the `ShinyApp` unless I preload the `Data` from the `server`.

If I do not read the `Data` before running the App it throws an error :

```
> runApp('example.R')
Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : object 'Data' not found
```

It works fine if I select all the code and run it.

Can someone please explain why and how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(12,selectInput("id_1","Choose the x axis",Data$Species)),
  column(12,plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Data=iris
  output$plot=renderPlot(
    ggplot(Data[Data$Species==input$id_1,],aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Length))+geom_point()+
      labs(x="Sepal Length",y="Petal Length",title=paste0("Sepal Length vs Petal Length for ",input$id_1))+
      theme(panel.background=element_blank())
  )
  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp('example.R')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the selectInput in the server function inside of a renderUI function, as it has to react to selected input. This is not working in Ui. And you have to include a `req(input$id_1)` in the renderplot function, so it waits until something is selected.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6,uiOutput("uimod")),
  column(6,plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Data=iris

  output$uimod <- renderUI({
    selectInput("id_1","Choose the x axis",Data$Species)
  })
  output$plot=renderPlot({
    req(input$id_1)
    ggplot(Data[Data$Species==input$id_1,],aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Length))+
      geom_point()+
      labs(x="Sepal Length",y="Petal Length",
           title=paste0("Sepal Length vs Petal Length for ",input$id_1))+
      theme(panel.background=element_blank())
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And why do you need the `runApp('example.R')`? Which example.R should be running there? 
If you want to start your shinyApp the function `shinyApp(ui, server)` is fine. If you select and run all the code that you show here, R will never come to the line runApp(), as it will open the shiny App 1 line before and so it doesnt execute the last line.

Comment: Thanks! example.R is just the name of the file in which the code is there. It came automatically when I clicked Run in RStudio. Thanks for the answer.